# VS2017 Getting numerous 'Cannot resolve symbol' errors in source but everything builds

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am getting numerous 'Cannot resolve symbol' errors in a VB.Net source code file. Everything in the solution builds without a problem.

Peek Definition and Goto Implementation work fine.

Thus far, I have tried the following:

1. Did a Build | Clean, closed VS 2017, re-started VS 2017 and did a Build | Rebuild Solution.
2. Cleared the ReSharper Cache, Closed VS 2017, Restarted VS 2017.
3. Closed VS 2017, Deleted all .SUO files, Restarted VS 2017.
4. Manually deleted all output followed by a Rebuild All.

Are there any other known solutions to this issue?

Answer (score 5):

Did you update Visual Studio recently? I had this happen after updating recently. The way I fixed it was within VS go into Tools -> Options -> "Projects and Solutions" and uncheck "allow parallel project initialization". Now load the solution and hopefully it will load ok now. Once everything looks good again, close the solution and go back and turn the option on again. Haven't seen the issue again after that.